# Why does my web server sometimes only transmit part of the response?

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, webserver

I have a piece of custom built web server code. It was written using the [evnet module.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/evnet)

It seems to the cut the length of the message when requested from a remote client. But when I use it on the same machine, it seems to deliver the full message. I can't figure out what the problem could be or how to diagnose it. I tested it using a web browser, `curl` and `nc`. It never delivered the full length message when requesting from remote clients.

[Here's](http://pastie.org/4551609) a simplified version of my webserver that still exhibits the problem. I am doing this on Ubuntu 11.04 with Python 2.7.1

Comment: OOPS! I corrected my question, Its actually the code for my webserver. I don't have any custom client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the socket immediately after calling `send()` to send a bunch of data. If there is data still buffered, it will be thrown away when you close the socket.

Instead, you should call [`shutdown(SHUT_WR)`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) on the socket to tell the remote end that you are finished sending. This is called a TCP "half-close". In response, the other end will close its side, and you will get a notification that the socket is no longer readable. Then, and only then, should you close the socket handle.

Comment: I don't see any online evnet documentation, but if it is just a layer over the underlying socket, this is likely why it is not sending the whole thing.  You need to test the result of `send` to see how much it sent, and keep sending the remainder.  Whereas on interface `127.0.0.1` it probably will send the whole thing.

Comment: @Greg @wberry `send()` is not from the socket, but a custom function that in turn calls a method of the evnet module. It appears that it does actually check to make sure all of the data is sent before closing, but I am not sure.